# How to open locked door to Frifle and the Grey Mauser?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I discovered Frifle and Grey Mauser in the gungeon behind a locked door. The door itself has eyes and highlights when you walk close as if you can interact with it, but doesn't unlock with a regular key.

When you interact, the door's eyes react as if I'm missing something, but the door doesn't speak or offer an obvious challenge. How does this door open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a cell key to open the cell.

There's a 100% chance that it's going to drop from an enemy (boss included) on the floor where the cell is on (the cell is always on the second floor).